# I am using pdf lib to generate pdf and want put a dyanamic table in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a dynamic table with a loop in pdf, but it is not working.

```
 pdfLib.Table.fromTextArray(
        context: context,
        data: <List<String>>[
          <String>[
            '#',
            'Product Name',
            'HSN',
            'Qty',
            'Unit Price',
            'MRP',
            'Disc%',
            'Disc Amnt',
            'Taxable Amnt',
            'SGST%',
            'SGST Amnt',
            'CGST%',
            'CGST Amnt',
            'Net Amnt'
          ],
          _list(),
        ],
      ),
```

_list here is a function which returns list of strings but it is only able to add one row in table,

```
for (var i = 0; i < _items.length; i++) {
  return <String>[
    (i + 1).toString(),
    _items[i].title,
    'HSN',
    _items[i].quantity.toString(),
    _items[i].price.toString(),
    _items[i].mrp.toString(),
    _items[i].discount.toString(),
    _item[i].gst,
    _item[i].amount  
    _item[i].sGst,
    _item[i].someitem,
    _item[i].cGst,
    _items[i].price,
    _items[i].quantity];
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`_list` needs to return a `List<List<String>>` as it need to return multiple string lists - one for each item. It can be written with `List.map()` like:

```
List<List<String>> _list() {
  return _items
      .map((item) => <String>[
            item.title,
            'HSN',
            item.quantity.toString(),
            // etc
          ])
      .toList();
}
```

which maps each item into a string list, and returns the list of lists.

You need to change how you use that to use a *spread operator* `...` so that the list of items is expanded into the overall list, like this:

```
  var data = <List<String>>[
    <String>[
      '#',
      'Product Name',
      'HSN',
      'Qty',
      'Unit Price',
      'MRP',
      'Disc%',
      'Disc Amnt',
      'Taxable Amnt',
      'SGST%',
      'SGST Amnt',
      'CGST%',
      'CGST Amnt',
      'Net Amnt'
    ],
    ..._list(),
  ];
}
```

Or, you could inline the whole operation with the `for` operator:

```
  var data = <List<String>>[
    <String>[
      '#',
      'Product Name',
      'HSN',
      'Qty',
      'Unit Price',
      'MRP',
      'Disc%',
      'Disc Amnt',
      'Taxable Amnt',
      'SGST%',
      'SGST Amnt',
      'CGST%',
      'CGST Amnt',
      'Net Amnt'
    ],
    for (var item in _items)
      <String>[
        item.title,
        'HSN',
        item.quantity.toString(),
        // etc
      ],
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, I prefer to fill the List separately, like:

```
`List<List<String>> salidas = new List();
    salidas.add(<String>['Title1','Title2', ... , 'Title n']);

    for(var indice=0;indice<records.length;indice++) {
       var recind = {
        'field1': records[indice].Stringfield1,
        'field2': records[indice].Stringfield2,
        ...
        'fieldn': records[indice].Stringfieldn
    };
    salidas.add(recind);
    }
 ...
 fpdf.Table.fromTextArray(context: context,data: salidas),
`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Generate Dynamic PDF
    _generatePdfAndView(context) async {
      final pw.Document pdf = pw.Document(deflate: zlib.encode);
      pdf.addPage(
        pw.MultiPage(
          build: (context) => [
            pw.Table.fromTextArray(
              context: context,
              data: <List<String>>[
                // These will be your columns as Parameter X, Parameter Y etc.
                <String>[
                  'Parameter',
                  'Price',
                ],
                for (int i = 0; i < featureNames.length; i++)
                  <String>[
                    // ith element will go in ith column means
                    // featureNames[i] in 1st column
                    featureNames[i],
                     // featureValues[i] in 2nd column
                    featureValues[i].toString(),
                  ],
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

**Hope that will work for you.**